# custom circular input type range slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

My plan is to create a circular slider where people can input the hour and minute values in the same button press.

Currently I have 12 input type sliders that change the minute part at the same time. What I'm trying to achieve next, is to change the changing slider on the same button press if I drag over another slider where it should activate the other slider (which would display the hours).

But the input type slider seems to be blocked when I click. is it even possible with an input type slider to change to another input type range slider without releasing the button?

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slider input[type="range"]');
const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-label');

sliders.forEach((slider, index) => {
  slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const sliderValue = slider.value;

    // Update the slider thumb position
    sliders.forEach((s) => {
      s.value = sliderValue;
    });

    // Update the label values
    labels.forEach((label) => {
      label.textContent = sliderValue;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

input[type="range"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* Hide input ranges by default */
}

.slider:hover input[type="range"] {
  visibility: visible;
  /* Make input ranges visible when hovering */
}

.slider1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.slider2 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.slider3 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.slider4 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.slider5 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.slider6 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.slider7 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.slider8 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.slider9 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.slider10 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.slider11 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.slider12 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider slider1">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider2">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider3">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider4">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider5">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider6">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider7">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider8">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider9">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider10">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider11">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider12">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="60">
    <span class="slider-label">60</span>
  </div>
</div>
```